# Insert foreign key into table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables.

basically i want to insert an `id` and a `string` into a table

However, `id` is a foreign key to another table in which `customerId` is the primary key

Furthermore my parent table has `name`

What i have, is `name` and the `string`that i get from a web ui. However, since i dont have the `id` that match the `customerid` of name in the parent table, i don't know how to insert it.

i got this so far, which by the way is my silly attempt to work my human logic around this issue:

```
INSERT INTO `PostDb`(`Offer`)
VALUES ("String") AND PostDb.id
WHERE CustomerDb.id = PostDb.id AND CustomerDb.name = "MyNameThatIHave"
```

What would work though. is that i do the following:

```
SELECT PostDb.id
FROM `PostDb` JOIN CustomerDb
WHERE `CustomerId` = CustomerDb.id AND CustomerDb.name = "MyNameThatIHave"
```

And then use the id that i get in a new insert command like this:

```
INSERT INTO `PostDb`(`CustomerId`, `Offer`) 
VALUES ("THE ID I GOT BEFORE","STRING")
```

Basically i want to achieve in ONE query, what the two before stated queries does

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `SELECT` to get values for insert:

```
INSERT INTO `PostDb`(`Offer`, customerid)
  SELECT 'Whatever', id FROM customerdb
    WHERE name = 'MyNameThatIHave'
```

Comment: But how can i get it to use that id from the select statement in my insert statement?

Comment: @Jeppe By writing that exact statement I wrote?

Comment: But i dont get why i type string? :-)

Comment: @Jeppe You type whatever you want to insert as the string for that table

Comment: Wow, that works! Thank you so much mate. 
I got confused because i thought that i would manually have to define customerId

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) function which gives you the last inserted `ID` PK provided that `ID` is an `auto_increment` column.

Once you get that, then you can insert in your child table in your FK column along with the rest attributes.

In that case, use a `INSERT INTO .. SELECT FROM` construct like

```
INSERT INTO `PostDb`(`CustomerId`, `Offer`) 
SELECT PostDb.`CustomerId`, 'Some Value'
FROM `PostDb` JOIN CustomerDb
ON `PostDb`.`CustomerId` = CustomerDb.id 
WHERE CustomerDb.name = "MyNameThatIHave";
```

Comment: i am really really intermediate to mysql. So i really dont know what Last_insert_ID() is. But yes, customerDB.id is AI

Comment: @JeppeChristensen, see edit in answer and go through the linked MySQL documentation for more information.

Comment: Oh wait. It should not be last inserted ID. I have 7 different entities in the table, and it could eg. be id=4

Comment: @JeppeChristensen, then your question is not clear enough. edit your post and explain further.

Comment: I will try mate :)

Comment: i added one more query now to explain what i want to achieve further :-)